# How do I align the circle (in pesudo class :after) and text vertically middle in this case?

Tags: css

Here is the code:

I've tried many times and searched my answers but none works.

```css
.tag-wrap a {
    font-size: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 99px 0 0 99px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(38 38 38 / 10%);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family:arial;
}

.tag-wrap a:before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2212%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2210%22%20cy%3D%2210%22%20r%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22white%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-wrap"><a href="#" >Label One</a><a href="#">Label Two</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a modern approach by using a **flexbox** or **grid** to vertically center the text.

And if you want the elements next to each other just use **inline-flex** or **inline-grid**

```css
.tag-wrap a {
    max-width: 10em;
    font-size: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 99px 0 0 99px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(38 38 38 / 10%);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family:arial;
}

.tag-wrap a:before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2212%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2210%22%20cy%3D%2210%22%20r%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22white%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-wrap"><a href="#" >Label One</a><a href="#">Label Two</a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

add `vertical-align: middle` to both the circle and the anchor.

```css
.tag-wrap a {
    font-size: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background: #333;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 99px 0 0 99px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(38 38 38 / 10%);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family:arial;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.tag-wrap a::before {
  vertical-align: middle;
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2212%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2210%22%20cy%3D%2210%22%20r%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22white%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    margin-right:4px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-wrap"><a href="#" >Label One</a><a href="#">jelly gap</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks but i think though the circle and text had aligned well, they are too up in the whole label's container.

Comment: the circle was rendered as inline-block, so the browser was treating it like a letter and putting space below it, setting the font size to 0 made it perfectly centered vertically

Comment: Cool. Looks great. However, the text is still a bit upside.

Comment: set the line height to 1.5 and changed the label for the second element to have letters that go below the line since the initial text was all above the line which may give the illusion that it's not centered

Answer (score 1):

If you have no problem with a verbose but more accommodating answer!! Changing the font size of the text changes the dimension of pseudo-class accordingly.

```css
span{
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 2em;
  position: relative;
  margin-block: 1em;
}

span::before{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  content:'';
  background:orchid;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-radius: 2em 0 0 2em;
}

span::after{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: calc(100% - 1.5em);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white; 
}
```

```html
<span>Label One</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily handle this problem with *FlexBox*. You do not need to use padding or anything else to place elements to the center.
**Just add the below styles to your code:**

```css
.tag-wrap a {
    display: flex;
    height: 26px;
    padding: 0 11px 0 8px;
    align-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
}

.tag-wrap a:before {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-wrap"><a href="#" >Label One</a><a href="#">Label Two</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add those lines with `display:flex` property and you want to center the whole text and circle to the center of that `div` you also should add `justify-content:center`

```css
.tag-wrap a {
    max-width: 10em;
    font-size: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 11px 5px 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    color: white;
    background: #333;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 99px 0 0 99px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgb(38 38 38 / 10%);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    font-family:arial;
}

.tag-wrap a:before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2212%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%3E%3Ccircle%20cx%3D%2210%22%20cy%3D%2210%22%20r%3D%2210%22%20fill%3D%22white%22%3E%3C%2Fcircle%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E);
    margin-right:4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag-wrap"><a href="#" >Label One</a><a href="#">Label Two</a></div>
```